# Custom UITableViewCell Best Practice?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

I am always subclassing UITableViewCell's and drawing them in code. Is there a good tool to visually get rect sizes so I don't have to guess and check all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw the cells in Interface Builder - see [Table View Programming Guide - scroll down to Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) - just make sure you follow the other recommendations regarding use of transparency, cell reuse, etc.

Comment: Fixed - as always, you need to be logged into your developer account.